# SSL unpinning Twitter android app

Tags: android

I want to run twitter app behind a proxy so i decompiled the app 
to read the source code.I have noticed that it is using this code

> https://github.com/moxie0/AndroidPinning/tree/master/src/org/thoughtcrime/ssl/pinning

to pin the certificate.
I patched the code to ignore pinning.But it is still not working.
So I run it in androbug debugger to see the source of the problem.After some digging around I have noticed that the runtime library libcore.net.http calls another trust manger than the one I have modified. And this library is not in the apk file. So what are my options now ?